# Line level voltage to drive LED display

Tags: led, voltage, sound, preamp

EDIT:  Please read the whole post before automatically down voting. I KNOW the diagram is crap.  That is what I am asking about.  It isn't my diagram.

Original post:

I Web searched a bit and searched this site, but I didn't really see a good answer.

I thought line level voltage was insufficient to switch a transistor and I thought an audio signal coming out of an amp or preamp was a sine wave anyway.

I thought those things made the seemingly simple idea of driving LEDs to pulse with sound or music a little more difficult.  Microphone input -> preamp -> rectify it to make a nice fat on/off dc signal -> drive something.

But I see this:
[leds respond to sound](http://howto.wired.com/wiki/Build_an_LED_Display_That_Responds_To_Music)

with a circuit that looks like:
[image]

I see other circuits (one at Instructables I think) that essentially do the same thing- connect the line level voltage directly to some transistors.

**My question:** I haven't a clue what is going on here.  Why does this work- or does it really?  What is happening?  Is it that the "audio source" is really headphone/speaker level and not the line level it may be billed at and thus enough to saturate the transistor?  Does this look like a recipe for disaster?

EDIT:  Trying to focus things per Red Gritty Brick.  I know the diagram is crap.  How would you do it right?

Comment: Link to the source of your schematic is now bad.

Answer (score 2):

That diagram is a rich collection of errors, to long to fit in a comment, so I'll make it an answer.

- your diagram shows PNP transistors, but wired the wrong way round. But the TIP31C that you show next to a PNP symbol is an NPN type...
- you have no resistor in the base wire of the transistors to limit the current. Put a 1k resistor there (in each each line)
- you have the LEDs pointing in the wrong direction, the arrow  must point towards the negative. The LED picture next to the symbol that is pointing in the opposite direction does not help for clarity.
- you have no resistor to limit the current through the LEDs. For standard 20 mA leds put a resistor of ( 12 - ( 4 X 2 )) / 0.02 ~= 220 ohm in series with each LED string.
- you used the symbol for a foto-transistor, which is a very different component than the power transistor you want (and should) use.

If you want to get this to work, either find a better instructable or dive into the theory yourself.

Comment: "I" don't have any of that.  I didn't make the diagram- in fact it seems wrong to me as well and that is the root of my question.  Frankly, I don't see how it would work as drawn.  Edit:  I'm hoping somebody will post the real way to do this.  Hint.

Comment: - I'm not sure you read my question.  You say "If you want to get this to work, either find a better instructable or dive into the theory yourself."  First off, I don't need your open hostility. Second, I thought I displayed a little better knowledge of what is going on than appears to be shown in the diagram.  You have done a fine job identifying several of the flaws in the diagram.  I was more interested in why this seems to work for the people that posted it and the better/right way to do this.

Comment: @MikeY your Question contains five separate questions, your comment contains a sixth (*"how to make LED brightness respond to a line-level audio signal"*). maybe you can edit your Question to focus on a single issue.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick - Please attribute the lack of a single focused question to not understanding the circuit that they posted.  What I am really after is a better understanding of why what they posted seems to work for them when I didn't think it would and Wouter certainly doesn't.

Comment: Not a real design question, it should be closed.

Comment: @LeonHeller  - Then please think of the question as "How would you design this correctly" and please respond.

Comment: @LeonHeller  Nothing constructive to add?

Comment: They are rubbish questions, why should I?

Comment: @LeonHeller  Seeing a an example of how it is being done wrong and asking how to properly make LEDs react to sound is a rubbish question?  Thank you for your opinion.  I disagree with you.

Comment: I don't see what's so bad with this question. Line level is about 1V peak-to-peak, so I suspect it the whole thing will work for loud music once modified appropriately - you could actually just swap the positive and negative terminals on the 12V, provided it's a battery and not ground-referenced to the line. The lack of current limiting will abuse everything a bit, but on a low duty cycle.

Comment: @pjc50  Thanks.  I think that helps confirm what I was thinking but wasn't sure about - which is the reason I posted.  I think the key words you used for me are "loud" (I read that "as make as big a signal as possible") and "abuse" (which I read as "the lack of resistors and protection diodes is stupid but it just might work anyway"). Now maybe if we are lucky, we'll get somebody to show us how to do it correctly.

Comment: @mikeY: I think I explained why the circuit you show won't work. If the author claims he has a working circuit that might be true, but it isn't the circuit you show us. (Judiging from the quality of the circuit I would not trust the author of it to be able to write down what he actually made.) If you apply the points I made you will probably get a working circuit.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen  I asked specifically "why does this work?" because the circuit seems to for those who are popularizing it in the several places I've seen it. PJC50 did a better job at working in that direction than you did. I think PJC thinks what I suspected- mainly that the input levels may really be higher than line level and that the circuit is somehow (I don't really know how) operating on the edge of abuse.  I would note that the opportunity to offer a better designed, functional circuit from a real EE is still available.

Comment: My answer to "why does this work" is "this does NOT". There might be something that works, but that is not the diagram you show.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen  I am aware that the diagram I posted doesn't look like it would work and I said as much.  You don't seem to read what other people write, nor do you seem to have anything positive to contribute.  Thank you for your time.  I'm still hoping someone will provide a little instruction and the outline of a good solid solution.

Comment: If you read my answer you have the outline of a good solution.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen  No I wouldn't.

Comment: If you ignore the correct polarities and interpret the symbols as the picture of the led and the npn transistor shown does, then the errors cancel out. Still having resistors would be better than having spares for when they burn out!

Comment: @mikeY - You're missing the critical point that Wouter et.al. are trying to get across. **What is in the drawing is not what the people doing the original writeup *actually* made.** They're equally poor in accurately depicting their circuit as they are in drawing a schematic.